# Explain the concept of "two haploid eggs fusing to produce a single diploid embryo"

Tags: society, evolution, reproduction, species, gender

So I'm creating a society that is hermaphroditic (specifically what I really want is a society where there's only one gender and both sexual partners experience pregnancy) so I've been doing research about that kind of concept, trying to get around the problem that in most cases hermaphroditic species evolve due to difficulty or rarity of finding a mating partner (I want this species to be social and form close nit families, which I dont see adapting if this is the problem). And I ended up coming across [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/95796/86763), which I really like the idea of, especially the part where having twins would be the norm, then I saw the first comment which adds more scientific language to it, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it or finding any useful research to elaborate.

So would I want to say that for this species, each partner has 2 "host haploid eggs" and the ability to produce "fertalizing haploid eggs", that fuse with the two host eggs, and form 2 diploid embryos? That way each partner on avarage will have twins? Would this still be considered a hermaphroditic mating system? How could this process be possible?

Comment: ? In animals, the definition of an egg-cell and a spermatozoid is that the egg-cell is large and motionless and the spermatozoid is small and mobile. In botany, they sometimes use the words "macrogamete" and "microgamete". That's all there is. In your fantastic world two egg-cells could fuse exactly like in our world a spermatozoid fuses with an egg-cell. In fact, in our world we do have organisms where all gametes are of the same size and general appearance -- see [isogamy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogamy).

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding Murbles, please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] as and when you have time for guidance as to how we work, enjoy the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Haploid cells**

There's two types of cells. Haploid and diploid. Depending on your biology grade, you might remember that you have chromosome pairs.  Humans have 23 Chomosome pairs, which makes a total of 46 chromosomes.

The pairs are important, as each is a sort if backup. If one has a flaw, most often the flaw isn't present as the other can prevent this.This is very well visible in colour blindness. Females have XX chromosomes. If one has a colour blindness flaw, it won't be a problem if the other doesn't have the flaw. You'll see normal. Males have an XY combination, of which the Y is a bit stunted. Some information is missing, like the ability to see colour. That means the X chromosome decides everything. If a flaw like colour blindness is present, there is no backup. That is why colour blindness is much more prevalent in males than females.

This is where the dominant and recessive genes come from. Blue eyes are recessive, so if one of the chromosomes is brown, you will have brown eyes.

Back to diploid and haploid. Diploid means that all chromosomes come in pairs, like in normal human cells. So in humans you have 23 *pairs*, for 46 total. Haploid means the chromosomes aren't ordered in pairs. In humans, that means you have 23 single chromosomes, for 23 total.

This happens in the reproductive cells. In the production of both sperm and egg cells a cell will devide into two, where each get half the chromosomes of a pair at random. That means reproductive cells are haploid by definition. That also means your suggestion of host and fertilising eggs makes sense. They are done by egg and sperm cells respectively in the real world.

**Twins**

The twin part is much easier. Depending on the species, multiple egg cells can be available with each reproduction cycle. In addition, a womb can stay in a way to accept more fertilised cells. As cells often accidentally lose some cells, these can nestle in the womb and start growing to become an identical twin. With a more accepting womb, this can happen more often.

**Hermaphrodites**

True hermaphrodite means they have access to both fully realised reproductive systems. For example, some snails are. They grapple each other and try to literally penetrate the other. The one that penetrates first is then the male. However, there is no reason both can't be inseminated.

An animal can have many more reasons to have both parties impregnated. Ask yourself, why does sex cost so much time and energy and can be loud? It is thought to be a mechanism to prevent reproduction if there is not enough safety and food/resources and one or both parties could die (besides a lot more advantages, like bonding). Your creatures have further raised stakes, as both parties are affected by a high energy costing pregnancy. This can further social bonding, as they're more reliant on each other or family/friends.

Although evolutionary paths can give you a lot of guidelines, like that Hermaphrodites happen mostly in difficult or rare situations to find a partner, we see these guidelines broken often enough. Egg laying mammals are rare if I remember correctly, but still we have the platypus and a few family members that can do this. Evolutionary paths aren't set in stone, so you can take a few liberties here and there.

Comment: Very informative, Thank you so much!